# How can i add a polyline using a Listener?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Hello i'm using Google API, Google Maps.

So far i've learned how to add Markers using onMapLongClickListener, now i want to do it with Polylines so after i can create a Polygon
This is my code:

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mMap = googleMap;

 mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {

        mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().add(latLng));
       mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
     }
 });
}}
```

Thanks

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your `onMapReady` like following.

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        final ArrayList<LatLng> latLngArrayList=new ArrayList<>();
        mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
                latLngArrayList.add(latLng);
                LatLng[] latLngs = new LatLng[latLngArrayList.size()];
                int c=0;
                for (LatLng latLng1:latLngArrayList) {
                    latLngs[c++]=latLng1;
                }
                mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().add(latLngs));
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: yeah, but what i meant is you click on the map and it should add a polyline and add a marker and same after that